# Is it harder to sneak when carrying a heavy load?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, does the weight I carry (other than armour worn) affect sneaking?

Comment: At one point when I was over my carrying capacity, I thought I was noisier and having a harder time sneaking. I'll have to do some testing to confirm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Skyrim manual:

> How stealthy you are is affected by many factors:
>
> - **Your Sneak skill only helps you when you are crouching**  The higher your Sneak skill, the easier  it is to remain undetected. Increase
>   your Sneak skill by staging successful stealth attacks, or by sneaking
>   within range of a target. There are a number of Sneak perks that grant
>   additional stealth bonuses.
> - **Line of sight**: An enemy is much less likely to detect you if he can’t see you.
> - **Darkness**: You are harder to see in darker areas.
> - **Movement**: You are hardest to detect when motionless, and easiest to detect when running.
> - **Sound**: Two-handed weapons make the most noise. One-handed weapons are quieter; daggers and bows are  silent. Casting spells makes both
>   sound and light. Heavier armor makes more noise when
>   moving.

So, the amount you're carrying doesn't make a difference, the stuff you have equipped *does* make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

it does not. the only thing it would affect would be the amount of loot you can steal from people.

keep in mind, how fast you are moving while sneaking does affect how well you can go undetected

Answer (score 0):

Do not wear heavy boots while sneaking. Boots affect sneaking a lot. The overall armor as well. How much you're carrying only affects your movement speed. And your sneak skill improves while you are sneaking , or doing a sneak attack. This [link](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sneak) ought to give you a lot of information regarding anything elder scrolls.